# Can I get all signed paperwork from previous employer?

Tags: united-states, contracts

Is a company legally required to provide all forms/contracts I signed with them?

I quit a job and the guy leading me through the exit process conveniently "forgot" to give me a copy of one of the forms I signed. He was a bully, had it out for me, and the company culture was awful, so there was potential for foul play and him making a mistake on purpose. I don't remember what was on the form, but I'd like to know now, as it may have important legal implications. The job was a US federal contract, so I may still be required to contact or report to the company under certain circumstances. (That's what the missing form might have been about)

Do I have any legal ground here when requesting the copies of the forms? Should I contact HR and ask them for copies of EVERYTHING? I don't want to sue the company or anything, I just want records of anything I signed, and hopefully I can move on for good and never be involved with this company again.

What is a subtle, tactful, and legal way to get copies of my signed forms, without raising alarm or making them fear of legal conflict? I really don't want to lawyer up and cause issues. I emailed HR several months ago and asked if there was an additional form, they said they could check, but never got back to me or confirmed anything.

What are the legal implications if they "lose" or hide the form, say there are no other forms, and conveniently find it later and don't tell me? Is it still legally binding?

Comment: Not sure if you're supposed to receive every copy of the forms you signed during the exit process.You'll receive a reliving letter (or a variant thereof) which should clearly mentions any remaining liabilities, that's it.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- if you're concerned about legal repercussions, your best bet is to contact a lawyer. Legal advice is not something we can provide.

Comment: @SouravGhosh no, he won’t. Relieving letters aren’t a thing in the US.

Comment: In general, you should receive your copy (not a photocopy, but one of the originals with their signatures) of any contracts when they're signed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a company legally required to provide all forms/contracts I signed with them?

Probably not.  It is up to you to make sure you've got all your paperwork.

> I don't remember what was on the form, but I'd like to know now, as it may have important legal implications.

How do you know it's important if you don't remember what was on it?  How will you know when you have it if you don't remember?

> What is a subtle, tactful, and legal way to get copies of my signed forms

Just call the main number, explain you're an ex-employee and ask if they can fax over your forms.  Unless you have a friend who still works there, this is likely the ONLY way.

> What are the legal implications if they "lose" or hide the form

Unless you decide to hire a lawyer over it none.  Even if you hire a lawyer, still probably none.  The right time to get a copy was your last day.